# Extending LVM partition with unallocated space on CentOS guest system

Tags: centos, lvm

I believe this is an easy question for people in the know.

I have ~100 GB unallocated hard disk space that I want to use to extend my home partition. What commands do I need to run?

```
[paul@localhost ~]$ lsblk  
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                    8:0    0   360G  0 disk
├─sda1                 8:1    0     1.5G  0 part /boot
└─sda2                 8:2    0   254.4G  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0    10G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0   1.4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0 243G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                   11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

What I want is the centos-home size to increase to the maximum possible (from 243G to about 340G)

Thanks!

*More info:*
This CentOS7 is running as a VM guest on a Windows 10 Host

I've found many guides online, but none were specifically answering my issue. One increased the centos-root partition instead of centos-home, so I reset the whole VM. Another guide was for moving space from root to home, so not what I need. It can't be difficult I'm just a noob. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I will change it. Couldn't copy it from the VM, I tried, will type it manually.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a partition (I assume that will be `sda3`)
2. Prepare it for use with LVM:

   ```
   pvcreate /dev/sda3
   ```
3. Add it to the existing volume group:

   ```
   vgextend centos /dev/sda3
   ```
4. Now `vgs` should show free space
5. In order to add all the free space to the logical volume:

   ```
   lvresize --extents +100%FREE centos/home
   ```
6. Resize the file system (it does not recognize the increased block device automatically), assuming it is ext[34]:

   ```
   resize2fs /dev/mapper/centos-home
   ```

Comment: Ok I tried to create a partition... this was again following some guide where some commands give warnings. Now when I run "$ sudo pvcreate /dev/sda3" it says "Device /dev/sd3 excluded by a filter." Whatever that means.

Comment: One site says "You may now see the message 'Device /dev/vdaX not found (or ignored by filtering)'. In that case the partition table needs to be reloaded using the command: partprobe /dev/vda" --- I ran this as well but doesn't change anything, it's still "Device /dev/sda3 excluded by a filter"

Comment: Ok after getting quite fed up, I deleted my new partition again, and then got it to work following this guide, replacing vda with sda, and having your steps open alongside which mirrored mostly. https://www.transip.eu/knowledgebase/entry/141-how-do-grow-partition-linux

Comment: @Paul If this solved your problem then you should accept my answer so that your question is shown as successfully answered.